# How to pin a program from a drive different than C: to the Start Menu?

Tags: taskbar, start-menu, user-interface, windows-10

I have several programs installed on another drive (`F:\`) than my system drive (`C:\`). On Windows 7 I had the possibility to pin those programs both to the Start Menu and the taskbar. I just had to right click on the icon in the task bar then click `Pin to Start Menu/Taskbar`.

Now (using Windows 10) I can only close it:

[image]]

Is there any way to pin a program on a drive other than `C:\` to the taskbar or the Start Menu?

Comment: Pin a shortcut that exists on the system drive

Comment: @Ramhound Tried, same issue, I can only close the window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a shortcut to your application, file, anything.
2. Move the shortcut to here: %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

   - This will make the shortcut appear in Start Menu "All Apps". May require restart
3. Find your new Start Menu item by searching or scrolling through "All Apps"
4. Pin it to start

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the shortcut doesn't appear in all apps.

Comment: Ok apparently it required a Reboot. Thanks for the answer, I hope they implement a more user friendly way in the future.

Comment: I hope so too, should be a lot easier.